# Create new dialog with 4 checkboxes and add the dialog UI.wxs

Tags: wix, wix3.5

How can I add a new dialog to the installation set of dialogs in WiX? Before the future selection dialog I want to pop up a dialog with 4 check boxes to add some extra files.

I have found some help on adding a checkbox to an existing dialog, but how can I add a new dialog?

I have tried this:
added the following inside  in my UI.wxs

```
<Dialog Id="NewDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="Conditions dialog">
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" />
    <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
    <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="OP1" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="160" Width="290" Height="17" Property="OPONE"  Text="Op1" />
    <Control Id="OP2" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="160" Width="290" Height="17" Property="OPTWO" Text="Op2" />
    <Control Id="OP2" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="160" Width="290" Height="17" Property="OPTHREE"  Text="Op3" />
    <Control Id="OP2" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="160" Width="290" Height="17" Property="OPFOUR" Text="Op4" />

  </Dialog>


<Publish Dialog="NewDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="FeaturesDlg"></Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="NewDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg"></Publish>
```

But the dialog in not popping up.

**UPDATE:** Now the dialog is showing up. But,
The checkbox is not allowing to uncheck and,
How to install a file based on the check box's check?

Answer (score 0):

You should define next step in LicenseAgreementDlg for creating your dialog. Check the markup code below:

```
<Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="NewDlg" Order="1"></Publish>        
<Publish Dialog="NewDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="FeaturesDlg"></Publish>
<Publish Dialog="NewDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg"></Publish>
```